# MVC razor view @model - is it possible to define multiple interfaces

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, model

Have Interface1 and Interface2, the question is it possible to use them in partial view as following

```
@model Interface1, Interface2
```

my studio underline everything as wrong statement.

I do realize that I can define Interface which inherited from Interface1, Interface2 as a workaround this limitation. But it would be nice to know if there some special syntax to do it directly.

Thanks.

Comment: No is not possible. And using an interface as a model does not make sense anyway - you need to use a concrete implementation.

Comment: It makes scene if you are creating partial view which uses two other partial view to render content. which of them uses Interface1 or Interface2 as a model. 
Sure at the end it will be a class instance but it may implement both interfaces and may implement only one of them, and rendered content should be appropriate.

Thanks for confirming that it is impossible anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Just use a single interface that that implements 2 or more interfaces